# How can I chain multiple ImageElement load events in Dart

Tags: dart

I converted a JavaScript background image loader to Dart, kinda like this: [Javascript image loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197673/javascript-image-loader)

And I use a Timer to check if the images are all loaded.
This works OK.

But in Dart there are chainable Futures and I was wondering if you could chain
the background loading of ImageElements...

```dart
ImageElement a = new ImageElement();
ImageElement b = new ImageElement();
ImageElement c = new ImageElement();

Future.wait([a.src='a.jpg', b.src='b.jpg', c.src='ca.jpg'])
  .then((List responses) => chooseBestResponse(responses))
  .catchError((e) => handleError(e));
```

Of course assigning src and the actual image loading is asynchronous so this won't work...

I also need some code to execute for each image once it is loaded.

Maybe I need to write my own FutureImageElement class, but I thought I'd ask first...

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Sure, you can use futures. Just use the `first` property of streams:

```dart
var a = new ImageElement(src: 'a.png');
var b = new ImageElement(src: 'b.png');
var c = new ImageElement(src: 'c.png');

var futures = [a.onLoad.first, b.onLoad.first, c.onLoad.first];

Future.wait(futures).then((_) => print('done'));
```

The text "done" will be printed when all three images are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to work with Futures for this?

Why not something like:

```dart
List<String> files = ["a", "b", "c"];
int imagesToLoad = files.length;
for (String fileName in files) {
    ImageElement pic = new ImageElement()
      ..src = "$fileName.jpg"
      ..onLoad.listen((Event e) {
          // do something when the file has finished loading

          imagesToLoad--;
          if (imagesToLoad == 0) {
            // do something when all images have loaded
          }
        })
    ;
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but I am wondering if there is a Dart "Future" way also. I noticed that onLoad returns an EventStreamProvider. I wonder if I can use that somehow. I feel this could teach me some advanced Future usage and I have a suspicion it is possible.